# How to change the style of an element when a specific class is present?

Tags: javascript

There's an idea to set a value to the "div" with an id if there is another class in HTML code. I am currently studying JS and I've faced a problem that this simple code doesn't work.

```
function change_visibility() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('mobile')) {
        document.getElementById('#cube').style.width = '10px';
    }
}
```

Comment: drop '#' from `#cube` string, you look by ID, not by selector.

Comment: This condition has no logic.

Comment: Do you know your `if` condition is being executed always? No matter there is an element with class `mobile` or not in your markup.

Comment: [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: this type of logic should be done in CSS and not JS

Comment: Put this in the console of your browser: `!![]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem #1

```
document.getElementById('#cube')
```

will find an element like

```
<elem id="#cube" />
```

but **not** an element like

```
<elem id="cube" />
```

To find the latter you need to omit the `#`:

```
document.getElementById('cube')
```

### Problem #2

```
document.getElementsByClassName('mobile')
```

will **always resolve to `true`** in your if-condition

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('mobile'))
```

**even if no elements with that class name can be found**.

You instead want to check the `length` of the HTMLCollection returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('mobile')`:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('mobile').length)
```

#### Explanation

Why does it return true even if no elements with that class name exist?

The DOM API that offers the method `document.getElementsByClassName` defines what type of data this method returns. The data type is an *array-like* data type called `HTMLCollection`. This data type is returned even in case `document.getElementsByClassName` finds no elements - it is simply a `HTMLCollection` that has no elements, very similar to an empty `Array` `[]`.

To find out what sort of `Boolean` value (`true`/`false`) an item resolves to when used in a condition, you can simply enter it in the console and implicitly **cast** it to a `Boolean` using double negation `!!`:

```js
console.log(!![])

let a = document.getElementsByClassName('weirdLongClassNameThatDoesReallyNotExistInTheDOM')

console.log(!!a)
```

So basically your code does this:

```
if (true) {
   document.getElementById('#cube').style.width = '10px';
}
```

which means the code inside the `if` block will always be executed.